# How to kill all hidden JVM threads?

Tags: tomcat, jvm, ormlite

I'm using Tomcat 7 for my staging in Ubuntu VPS, and currently I found that: every time I shutdown tomcat, to redeploy updated war, I can see there are many **SEVERE** warnings regarding possible of memory leak caused by:

1. **Quartz** job (even thou I already start quartz job instance using quartz servlet, which supposed to be destroyed when ever the container destroyed - but actually not all)
2. **Ormlite** that has ongoing issues with ThreadLocal (even thou I already using Tomcat conn pool and accessing it through JNDI lookup),

The problem comes after I redeploy a few times, it seems that JVM cannot/has not released some sockets that should be use by tomcat, so tomcat somehow cannot be started at all. So what I did is restarting the entire Ubuntu by issuing command:

```
$ shutdown -r now
```

and after that I can start my Tomcat again.

My question is: can I use command:

```
$ pkill -f 'java -jar'
```

to kill all JVM hidden threads?

Thanks

Comment: This is not appropriate for SO.  Couple comments though: 1) i suspect the severe warnings are not the issue 2) you should never have to restart your OS if one of the applications runs out of memory.

Comment: Gray, ok thanks ... maybe my statements regarding some products that makes this question not appropriate sorry for that. But before I erase this question, can you please at least confirm whether or not I can use pkill -f 'java -jar' command to kill running JVM that might still holds some socket resources caused by my bad codings?

Comment: I'd think you'd want to restart tomcat.  No idea if you can kill the jars underneath it.

Comment: Ok I edit the above question after I got another incident last night and read the errors more carefully, hopefully my question now is appropriate :) ...
By the way, I'm using visualvm now for profiling my app, hopefully I can see whether JVM is really dead after shutting down tomcat ... or still live somewhere behind because it cannot release some resources ... but I'm still looking for a good answer ...